# Problem with LINQ Filters in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: linq, parsing, filter, telerik, radgrid

I have a problem using Telerik RadGrid.
When I apply a filter on a data column, I use the filter expression as a Linq expression.
So (server side) I parse it with Dynamic Linq (from MIcrosoft LINQ examples) in NeedDataSource handler.
The problem is that when I specify "Start With" as a filter, I receive the following as "Linq expression":

```
(iif(Name == null, "", Name).ToString().StartsWith("A"))
```

What is "iif"???? What corresponds to "iif"????
Usage is obvious: handling nulls....

The strange thing is that when I apply the filter on a grid that loads data from web services and not from server side callback, all works and this issue don't raise.
Two ways, two parsing function, not only a common one.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Dynamic LINQ `iif(x,y,z)` is another syntax for the ternary if `x ? y : z`, the same name was [used in VB for some time ("Immediate IF")](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2007/05/08/20433.aspx)

In this case, it looks like it a [null-coalescing operator ??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), but it seems that Dynamic LINQ doesn't support that

```
(Name ?? string.Empty).ToString().StartsWith("A")
```

Maybe try to substitute the iif with the ternary notation? Can you clarify what is the exact error that happens?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that RadGrid specify iif, not me! This is the problem!

Comment: @Marco: what is the problem with that "iif"? It should be easily parsed by Dynamic LINQ... why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: DynamicLinq code (from Microsoft examples - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) does not parse iif. That's the problem.

Comment: @Marco: that's strange... iif() is in the supported operations table, open the Dynamic Expressions.html from the link you gave

Comment: You are right, I have done a mistaken question. The problem is not on iif (sorry! :)), but on consequent ToString(). Iif evaluated generically as an object, not a string. ToString() is mandatory, but SQL provider does not know how to translate this!

Comment: @Marco: What will happen if you remove the "ToString()" from the string filter? Are you sure it fails?

Comment: I cannot remove it! The code is generated by Telerik RadGrid and I'm not able to find any way to intercept the code generation...

Comment: @MarcoParenzan: You should update the question to include any new information.